# echo each line from txt in in while loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I'm doing a simple script that I provide a list and the script outputs with the location of the store.  But I have problems in the output because I want this output

```
echo "$stores location is $locations"
store1.com location is New York
```

But I get this as response

```
Processing store1.com
Processing store2.com
location is New York
location is Chicago
location is Phoenix
Processing store3.com
```

(Im new programming)

```bash
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
        printf "No file name specified\nExecute script.sh [NameOfFile]\n"
        exit
fi
now=$(date +"%m%d%Y%H%M")
fileName=Results_$now.txt

while read stores;
do
    echo "Processing $stores"
    locations=$(curl -silent https://mysite.com/location/$stores | grep -P -o 'Location.*?<div class="row">' | sed -e :a -e 's/<[^>]*>//g;/</N;//ba' | sed 's/./& - /12')
    
    echo "$stores location is $locations"
    echo -e "$stores location is $locations" >> $fileName
done < $1
```

Comment: Seems like the processes run in parallel - which is a bit odd in my view. Nevertheless try the following: `locations=$(curl ...) & wait` to ensure that setting the location variable is done before the next step. `wait` pretty much does what the command's name suggests, for more info, use `man wait`.

Comment: Hello @FelixJN any recomendation to make the same but not run in parallel?

Comment: Well ... yes? As said, add `& wait` in the `locations=`-line. Did you try that?

Comment: @FelixJN I add like this locations=$(curl ...) & wait  but only display location is

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot about the [caveats of `wait`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/669185) ... a background process does not work for assigning variables.

Comment: @FelixJN and there are a way to avoid to run in parallel without use wait?

Comment: `command1 && command2` will make command2 run only when command1 succeeds. In your case `location=$( ... ) && echo "$stores loaction is $location"`.  You may use a newline after `&&` for better readability.

Comment: I don't see how, in the same loop body, `echo "Processing $stores"` can produce a store name, but then `echo "$stores location ..."` does not produce the store name, without any intervening assignment to `stores=`.  The code does not match the output.

Comment: @Kaz The value in `$stores` ends with a carriage return character. It's a DOS text file they are reading.  That's my guess, at least. And the space character before `location` was probably deleted as the question was written because they thought it wasn't important.