# Understanding backgrounded variable assignments and the wait command

Tags: bash, shell-script

In `man bash` it says:

> wait [-fn] [id ...]
>
> Wait for each specified child process and return its termination status.  Each id may be a process ID or a job specification; if a job spec is given, all processes in that job's pipeline are waited for.  If id is not given, all currently active  child  processes are waited for, and the return status is zero.  If the -n option is supplied, wait waits for any job to terminate and returns its exit status.

And typical examples like

```
 command1 & command2 & command3 & wait
```

will mean the three commands run in parallel and the next step is only done once ALL of them are finished.

My problem lies in the results of these two bash scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 1 2 3 ; do
  a=$i
  echo "$a is $i"
done 2>/dev/null
```

Result:

```
1 is 1
2 is 2
3 is 3
```

Pretty much what I expected. Now I assume assigning the variable is a long process, so I wait for it:

```
#!/bin/bash
  for i in 1 2 3 ; do
  a=$i & wait
  echo "$a is $i"
done 2>/dev/null
```

Result is:

```
3 is 1
3 is 2
3 is 3
```

and I am quite baffled for the following reasons:

1. The only process `wait` should be waiting to finish is assigning the variable, then the next step in the script should be run (`echo`). `a=3` should only happen in the last iteration of the loop.
2. As far as I know, `for`-loops are run in subshells and `wait` has a scope only for the shell it was launched in. So it should not even be waiting for the `for`-loop to finish (as this is the parent).
3. At no point have I specified the `echo` to run in parallel to some other process, so I did not expect a racing condition.

So why is the `a`-variable set with the last loop iteration when the variable `$i` is not? What part of the `wait` command did I misunderstand? The behavior is completely off my expectations.

GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1) on a 5.7.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 Linux kernel.

Unsetting `a` beforehand makes the second script return this

```
 is 1
 is 2
 is 3
```

i.e. the variable is never set and was dragged from my previous run.

Comment: You are not posting the correct output of your second script. Try it again, but unset the variable `a` first (with `unset a`).  You can't assign a variable in a background task and then expect it to be set in the parent shell.

Comment: @Kusalananda That makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for` loops don't run in a subshell, e.g. you can have `for i in 1 2 3; do a=foo; done; echo $a` and it'll print `foo`, even though the variable is used outside the loop. The value of the loop variable is also whatever it was last assigned to by the loop (which might not be the last value, if the loop was `break`'ed out of).

But using `&` *does* put that command in a subshell, and doing `a=$i &` makes the assignment happen in the subshell only. You could of course use the assigned value in the subshell too:

E.g.:

```
a=1;
{ a=2; echo "subshell: $a"; } &
echo "main: $a";
wait;
echo "after: $a"
```

would print

```
main: 1
subshell: 2
after: 1
```

do something like `{ a=$i; echo "$a"; } &` to verify.

Having the backgrounded commands access (and modify!) variables in the main shell would require some syncronization between the processes, and that would bring complexity to the shell, for probably relatively minor gain.

If you *do* need it though, e.g. if you have a long-running command you want to run in the background, but need the output of, you'll have to do something like storing the output temporarily in a file, e.g.

```
tmp=$(mktemp -d)
some long process > "$tmp/a" &
another long process > "$tmp/b" &
wait
a=$(< "$tmp/a")
b=$(< "$tmp/b")
...
rm -rf "$tmp"
```

Or use something like GNU Parallel that's purpose-built for running commands in parallel. It also has the `parset` command which should be able to assign values to a shell variable.

As for why you got `3` from `$a` on each iteration of the loop, that's probably because you'd run the first loop before, and it'd left `a` to `3`. With all the subsequent assignments shoved in the subshell, that's the value that remained in `a` for the main shell, for the whole loop.

Comment: With parset it looks like this: `parset a,b ::: 'some long process' 'another long process'`